# Read multiple xls files from zip file

Tags: apache-poi

I'm trying to read multiple xls files that are in a .zip file using the code below. I'm getting `missed end of block` error. Do I need to add a EOF kind of character at the end of the byte array before I send it to poi?

The code below:

```
val zipStream=new ZipInputStream(inputStream)
var zipEntry = null

while(zipEntry = zipStream.getNextEntry != null){
    val bytes=new Array[Byte](zipEntry.getSize.toInt)
    zipStream.readBytes(bytes)
    val xlsByteStream = new   ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)
    val workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(xlsByteStream)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val zipStream=new ZipInputStream(inputStream) 
var zipEntry = null 

while({zipEntry = zipStream.getNextEntry; zipEntry != null})
{ 
    val bytes=new Array[Byte](1024)
    val bos = new ByteArrayOuputStream(zipEntry.getSize.toInt)
    while({i=zipStream.read(bytes);i>0}) {
        bos.write(bytes, 0, i)
    }
    bos.close
    val xlsByteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray) 
    val workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(xlsByteStream) 
}
```